# custome domain name cannot display path on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am running my APP on Heroku with a name: http://appname.herokuapp.com

Now I have a personal domain: http://www.appname.com

I managed to post my personal domain to heroku name successfully. So when people visit http://www.appname.com, they will be redirected to http://appname.herokuapp.com.
However, the domain path is not displayed. For example, if I have a link on http://appname.herokuapp.com/path/to/destination, I can get that page, but the domain name is always showing http://www.appname.com which is supposed to be http://www.appname.com/path/to/destination.

My APP is written in NodeJS, so if necessary , I can change the route function inside.

Thanks

Derek

Comment: how do you redirect from your website to herokuapp?

Comment: @HirenS. I have a "web alias" and "CNMAE" from  http://www.appname.com to http://appname.herokuapp.com.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using silent redirects/forwarding features of your domain registrar, which will not work for URL paths. You need to use/configure a DNS server to perform the routing. In your case simply create a CNAME DNS record from www.appname.com to appname.herokuapp.com

Comment: Actually no. I have a "web alias" and "CNMAE". I am not using redirects and forwarding.